# bat files to move files to month folders based on file name

Tags: batch-file

I have files in a folder (`C:/location1`). Files are as:

```
 A-14-0005 - Title1 - 06202017.pdf
 B-14-1111 - Title2 - 06202017.pdf
 B-15-7676 - Title3 - 06202017.pdf
```

I need to move these to another location (`c:/location2`). If current Month is January, then create folder `2017` (for this year), then create subfolder `JANUARY`, if current month is June, then create subfolder `JUNE`. Then move the 3 files into this folder.

I have not written one batch file before and looking for some help/ideas on creating one to start this task. Any links else where as tutorial for me to begin will be great as well. Thanks

Comment: Why is January shortened to JAN but June is kept as June instead of being shortened to JUN?

Comment: it can be January

Comment: Do you have a specific question? If not then let me suggest to start collecting your own ideas and to start implementing the script based on them; when you have problems come back here. If you expect somebody to write a script for you, you are totally wrong here. Please learn [ask]!

Comment: What about extensions - your file names do miss them?

Answer (score 1):

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "Dir1=c:\location1"
Set "Dir2=c:\location2"

:: Build Mon[01..12] array
Set Cnt=100
For %%A in (Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
  ) Do Set /A Cnt+=1&Set Mon[!Cnt:~-2!]=%%A
::Set Mon[

For /f "delims=" %%A in (
  ' Dir /B/A-D "%Dir1%\?-??-???? - * - *.pdf" ^|findstr "[01][0-9][0-3][0-9]20[0-9][0-9]\.pdf$" '
) Do (
  Set "File=%%~nA"
  Call Set "MoveTo=%Dir2%\!File:~-4!\%%Mon[!File:~-8,2!]%%\"
  MD "!MoveTo!" >Nul 2>&1
  Move "%%~fA" "!MoveTo!"
)
```

Sample tree of the result:

```
> Tree /F .
C:\LOCATION2
└───2017
    └───Jun
            B-15-7676 - Title3 - 06202017.pdf
            B-14-1111 - Title2 - 06202017.pdf
            A-14-0005 - Title1 - 06202017.pdf
```

Comment: Well done, Aacini! **`;)`** Ops, you are _not_ Aacini! Well done anyway... I just would use the full `Month` name for the array in order to be clearer.

Comment: lotpings,when i tried running this from my c:\users\public location, it says UNC path not supported. i do need to run it from a network shared location. how to rectify this?

Comment: But `c:\users\public` is local, so I assume the batch itself is stored on a share? How excatly do you set Dir1/Dir2?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set month-num=%date:~3,2%
set year-num=%date:~6,10%
IF "%month-num:~0,1%"=="0" SET month-num=%month-num:~1%
FOR /f "tokens=%month-num%" %%a in ("January February March April May June July August September October November  December") do set mo-name=%%a

if not exist "C:\location2\%year-num%" md C:\location2\%year-num%\%mo-name%"
copy "C:\location1\A-14-0005 - Title1 - 06202017.*" "C:\location2\%year-num%\%mo-name%\" /y
copy "C:\location1\B-14-1111 - Title2 - 06202017.*" "C:\location2\%year-num%\%mo-name%\" /y
copy "C:\location1\B-15-7676 - Title3 - 06202017.*" "C:\location2\%year-num%\%mo-name%\" /y
pause
```

Comment: Presuming the file names are just a sample, it's of  not much use to have them static in a batch. Also a move was required not a copy.

Comment: the file extensions will be .pdf